# EKS Fargate pod isolation

Tags: kubernetes, aws-fargate, amazon-eks

In ECS with Fargate, we can manage service isolation via security group. However that is no longer the case with EKS on Fargate.

Is there a way where pods on the same cluster can be isolated from each other like a Network Policy? I know this is possible with kubernetes but it needs to be implemented by the network plugin. Tried to install the network provider listed [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/declare-network-policy/#before-you-begin) without success as it needs daemonset (limitation of eks fargate: `Cannot run Daemonsets, Privileged pods, or pods that use HostNetwork or HostPort.`)

Answer (score 0):

This is something we are tracking in this [roadmap item](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/625). There isn't a viable workaround for now. As you pointed out when using EC2 we'd suggest to use the [Calico network policy engine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/calico.html) but with Fargate there is no DaemonSet support and it can't be used.

Given the SG associated to a pod is defined at the cluster level, one way to try to mitigate this would be to spread like-pods across different clusters where the pod SG is configured for that specific type of workload BUT this will mean more work and higher control plane costs.